# Transferring Strings between two Hashmaps and an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have two `HashMap`: `map1<Key1,Value1>` and `map2<Key2,Value2>`, and one `ArrayList<Value3>`,
with Key1, Key2, Value1, Value2, Value3 all String,

Is it possible to extract Key2 from map2 and Value3 from my List and put them in map1?

The final result should be like this `map1<Key2,Value3>`.

Comment: What is `map1<Key1,Value1>`? A `Map<String, String> map1` that someone did `map1.put("Key1", "Value1")`?

Comment: How is Value3 related to Key2?

Comment: related with its positions, First with first second with second and so

Comment: without seeing your current attempt, this is not a real question.

Comment: Well i tought about it and i don't know how to loop 2 maps at the same time.

Comment: Please elaborate on the contents of the maps and the list and what you would like the results to be, or describe rigorously the process. It is unclear what you are looking for

Comment: You should edit your question - I wrongly assumed from `map1<Key1,Value1>` that `map1` is `HashMap<Key1,Value1>` where `Key1` and `Value1` are some classes, where in fact they are String.

Comment: i don't know if tried to read the question before you wrtite your comment, did you see the second line `with Key1, Key2, Value1, Value2, Value3 all String,`

Comment: @HossamOukli I noticed that later (after reading your comment of my answer), but when you write something like `ArrayList<Value3>`, it usually means in Java a generic `ArrayList` with type parameter `Value3`, and that's what confused me. If your `ArrayList` and `HashMap` are generic, you should use the correct type parameter - `ArrayList<String>` and `HashMap<String,String>`. Otherwise, you shouldn't use `<` and `>` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 2 iterators and a single loop :

```
Iterator<String> iter1 = map2.keySet().iterator ();
Iterator<String> iter2 = list3.iterator ();
while (iter1.hasNext() && iter2.hasNext ()) {
  map1.put (iter1.next(), iter2.next());
}
```

**EDIT :**

Regarding `Miserable Variable`'s comment :

The order in which `iter1` iterates over the keys of `map2` is undefined, unless the type of `map2` is `LinkedHashMap`, is which case the keys will be iterated in the order they were inserted to the map.

Comment: You do realize the iteration order in `map2.keySet()` is undefined and there is no guarantee what `map1` will have at end, except that the keys in it will be some subset of `map1`?